Detailed form I created with WordPress nex form
I have a form that I created with nex-form on WordPress. I want to do something like this in a part of the form, but I think there is no such feature in the form itself. For example, there is a select box in the form of a main dish. When you select pizza from here, I want the pizza types to appear on the other select box. This is related to this issue. Can anyone help?
I tried to do it through the form, but I guess it doesn't have such a structure.

From what i see they offer conditions on fields - https://basixonline.net/nex-forms-docs/version-8/conditional-logic/
